# Supressing or Whiteboxing issue

Tags: mocking, powermockito

I have a Logger that is private static final which utilizes a server. I would like to suppress the Logger method debug, or suppress any and all interactions with the variable.
I declare the logger in LoggingClass

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger("LoggingClass");
```

The javadoc for the debug is :

```
public abstract void debug(String s, Object aobj[]);
```

In the test class I have tried:

```
PowerMockito.suppress(PowerMockito.method(Logger.class, "debug", String.class, Object[].class));
```

Problem : Throws toomanyMethodsException

===========

```
 Logger nullLogger= null;
 LoggingClass lc= new LoggingClass(); //This is the class that uses the logger
 Whitebox.setInternalState(lc, "LOGGER",nullLogger);
```

Problem: Throws that Whitebox can not find the instance field LOGGER.

Any assistance would be appreicated

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
suppress(everythingDeclaredIn(LoggerFactory.class));
```

The import statements are

```
import static org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberMatcher.everythingDeclaredIn;
import static org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberModifier.suppress;
```